# Using acronyms in tags

Tags: discussion, support

There are a ton of acronyms is the world of aviation.  This could lead to duplicate tags, and some non-acronym tags, and some acronym tags.  Before the site goes public [knock on wood] we should decide to exclusivity use acronyms or not.

Ideally there would be a way to have "link" tags, so when someone types in UAV it links to the unmanned-aerial-vehicle tag, similarly FAA to Federal-Aviation-Administration.  Is there a way using the current SE software to do this - if not is it a capability we could add?

Comment: See [What tags should we use for FAR, FAA, AIM, etc.?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-tags-should-we-use-for-far-faa-aim-etc) and [Should the tag be air-traffic-control or atc (and other abbreviations)?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-the-tag-be-air-traffic-control-or-atc-and-other-abbreviations) for some more on this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general consensus is sometimes we use acronyms, and sometimes we don't (i.e. there's no definitive consensus) -- where we do have a pretty good consensus is that the acronym and its expansion should be synonyms ((e.g. [atc](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atc) --> [air-traffic-control](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-traffic-control)), which is how the Stack Exchange software deals with these sorts of duplicate tags: Typing either `ATC` or `Air-Traffic-Control` into the tag box will bring up the master tag.

Some acronyms are pretty universal and easy to figure out (like [faa](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faa)). Others (like [iaps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iaps), [ppl](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ppl), [efb](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/efb)) may be a little harder for people not familiar with them, and we might want to consider using the expanded tag as the primary tag (assuming it fits in the tag character limit).

If you see any tags that you think are particularly obtuse let us know and we can talk about renaming them & setting up synonyms :)